# Ошибка в Intel haxm в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

У меня возникает ошибка при установление Intel haxm в Android Studio.
Вот сама ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: И там есть 2 вещи: логи и ссылка на инструкцию. Смотрели?

Comment: Могу только скрин прислать лога.

Comment: Он у меня большой.

Comment: т.е. скопировать часть текста и вставить его вопрос для тебя непосильная задача? Никому тут скрин не нужен, никто не будет в него вглядываться.